# Best way to store two related projects in the same git repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have to projects (one is a front end application, another is the back end logic) both related to each other, but housed in different server locations.

I want to keep them in the same git repo (so they can share issue tracking, and so i can link/reference commits between the two).

Is it a bad practice to have branches like `frontend-master` and `backend-master`? or should i just not go about this route and make two separate repos?

The key here is that the two branches will **never** be combined into one folder/repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a very bad idea. That isn't at all what branches are for.

If you want to put them in the same repo, just make two top-level directories.

The best solution would be to make two repositories.